# Unusual initializer for char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, literals

I have the initializer for char array:

```
static const char dtmf_positions[] = "123A-------" "456B-------" "789C-------" "*0#D-------" "----E------" "-----F-----" "------G----" "-------H---" "--------J--" "---------K-" "----------L";
```

Can somebody explain, how to get some symbol by index, eg symbol '4'. Thank you.

Ok, then I have additional question. Is there any convenient way to access array elements by row and column index in above kind of array, like we do with two dimensional array?

Comment: So knowing for symbol '4' we have row_index = 1 and column_index = 0, how can i compute dtmf_positions[row_column_index] for this symbol? Can it works this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From C99 specs, **5.1.1.2 Translation phases**

> 6. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

You can find similar text in other C specs also.

So

`"abc" "def"` would become `"abcdef"` during translation phase.

So your definition is similar to:

```
static const char dtmf_positions[] = "123A-------456B-------789C-------*0#D-----------E-----------F-----------G-----------H-----------J-----------K-----------L";
```

I hope now you can find index for any symbol :)

---

EDIT: Your additional question:

```
 
                               /* Col 012345678910 */
static const char dtmf_positions[] = "123A-------"  /* Row 0 */
                                     "456B-------"  /* Row 1 */
                                     "789C-------"  /* Row 2 */
                                     "*0#D-------"  /* Row 3 */
                                     "----E------"  /* Row 4 */
                                     "-----F-----"  /* Row 5 */
                                     "------G----"  /* Row 6 */
                                     "-------H---"  /* Row 7 */
                                     "--------J--"  /* Row 8 */
                                     "---------K-"  /* Row 9 */
                                     "----------L"; /* Row 10 */
#define NCOLS (sizeof("123A-------") - 1)
#define FETCH_CHAR(ROW,COL) dtmf_positions[ROW * NCOLS + COL]
```

After this [you can access](http://ideone.com/mPgHUv) any character with `FETCH_CHAR(R,C)`

Answer (score 2):

This is a single C literal. The language allows you to split string literals by adding quotes on both sides of a "gap", and inserting whitespace in between ([demo](http://ideone.com/J3eY5S)):

```
char *s = "AB" "CD";
printf("%s\n", s);
```

is the same as

```
char *s = "ABCD";
printf("%s\n", s);
```

This is usually done for convenience when formatting your code: line breaks are allowed, too, so you can make parts of the literal appear in vertical columns:

```
static const char dtmf_positions[] = "123A-------"
                                     "456B-------"
                                     "789C-------"
                                     "*0#D-------"
                                     "----E------"
                                     "-----F-----"
                                     "------G----"
                                     "-------H---"
                                     "--------J--"
                                     "---------K-"
                                     "----------L";
```

So if you would like to find the index of character `'4'`, start counting at zero, and skip over the "gaps" in your literal to get the index (you should get 11).

Answer (score 2):

What is confusing you?

```
char a[] = "someString";
```

is same as

```
char a[] = "some" "String";
```

So if you know how to access the first array then you are good to do the same for the second one.

```
int i;
size_t len = strlen(a);
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
printf("%c ",a[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

simply:

```
char c = dtmf_positions[11];
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of arrays in C, the index starts from 0. So if you want to access the first element of array you can use dtmf_positions[0]. In case you donot know the index of the elements either you can use a loop to traverse out the array and check for the elements or you can create some kind of maps which would store the indexes of all the elements (in case of character repetition) and than whenever you want to check if the element exists or not and what their positions are you can use this map.

Comment: Thanks Mohit that would again be a good option. Your answer looks good but can't upvote as of now :-)

Answer (score 0):

The declaration

```
static const char dtmf_positions[] = "123A-------" "456B-------" "789C-------" "*0#D-------" "----E------" "-----F-----" "------G----" "-------H---" "--------J--" "---------K-" "----------L";
```

is the same as

```
static const char dtmf_positions[] = "123A-------456B-------789C-------*0#D-----------E-----------F-----------G-----------H-----------J-----------K-----------L";
```

which creates a `static const char` array and initializes it with `"123A-------456B-------789C-------*0#D-----------E-----------F-----------G-----------H-----------J-----------K-----------L"`

If you want to get a character just use `dtmf_positions[n]` where `n` is a number between 0 and 121(121 is the `\0` character)